# Effective Mordell for (twists of) hyperelliptic curves in $$\mathbb{P}(1,1,g+1)$$

Tags: nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry

We consider the following model for a hyperelliptic curve:

$$\displaystyle C_F : z^2 = F(x,y), \deg F = 2g+2, F \in \mathbb{Z}[x,y]$$

with $F$ homogeneous and non-singular. We also consider twists of the curve, given by $C_{a,F} : az^2 = F(x,y)$ with $a \in \mathbb{Z} \setminus\{0\}$.

Let us consider a very basic height which measures the complexity of the $C_{a,F}$'s, given by $H(C_{a,F}) = \max\{|a|^{1/(g+1)}, |f_0|, \cdots, |f_{2g+2}|\}$ where the $f_j$'s are the coefficients of $F$.

When $g \geq 2$, we know that $C_{a,F}(\mathbb{Q})$ is always finite by Faltings' theorem. Is there a conjectured polynomial bound on the (naive) *height* of elements of $C_{a,F}(\mathbb{Q})$, as a function of $H(C_{a,F}(\mathbb{Q})$? I believe that if one assumes the $abc$-conjecture one can prove actual upper bounds for the height of elements in $C_{a,F}(\mathbb{Q})$, but this bound (super-exponential in $H(C_{a,F})$) looks way too large to be optimal.